# How do you reinterpret structs using pointers?

Tags: c#

I'm converting some C++ code to C#. I want to reinterpret a byte array as a struct as you can easily do in C++.
I'd rather avoid serialization or reflection and just use pointers instead, I'm wondering if that is possible.

This is the struct that I want to reinterpret from a file:

```
public struct MS_DOS_Stub
{
    UInt16 e_magic;                     // Magic number
    UInt16 e_cblp;                      // Bytes on last page of file
    UInt16 e_cp;                        // Pages in file
    UInt16 e_crlc;                      // Relocations
    UInt16 e_cparhdr;                   // Size of header in paragraphs
    UInt16 e_minalloc;                  // Minimum extra paragraphs needed
    UInt16 e_maxalloc;                  // Maximum extra paragraphs needed
    UInt16 e_ss;                        // Initial (relative) SS value
    UInt16 e_sp;                        // Initial SP value
    UInt16 e_csum;                      // Checksum
    UInt16 e_ip;                        // Initial IP value
    UInt16 e_cs;                        // Initial (relative) CS value
    UInt16 e_lfarlc;                    // File address of relocation table
    UInt16 e_ovno;                      // Overlay number
    #region ReservedWords          
    UInt16 e_res1;                      // Reserved words
    UInt16 e_res2;                      //Cant initialize an array in a struct in C#
    UInt16 e_res3;
    UInt16 e_res4;
    #endregion                      
    UInt16 e_oemid;                     // OEM identifier (for e_oeminfo)
    UInt16 e_oeminfo;                   // OEM information; e_oemid specific
    #region ReservedWords2
    UInt16 e_res5;                      // Reserved words
    UInt16 e_res6;
    UInt16 e_res7;
    UInt16 e_res8;
    UInt16 e_res9;
    UInt16 e_res10;
    UInt16 e_res11;
    UInt16 e_res12;
    UInt16 e_res13;
    UInt16 e_res14;
    #endregion                                      // Reserved words
    UInt32 e_lfanew;                    // File address of new exe header 
};
```

This is the method I'm calling:

```
static unsafe Dictionary<string, UInt32> dumpSymbols(ref byte[] bin)
{
    fixed (byte* pBin = bin)
    {
        MS_DOS_Stub* stub = (MS_DOS_Stub*)(pBin);

        if(stub->e_magic != IMAGE_DOS_SIGNATURE)
        {
            throw new FileLoadException("Error, Invalid file. DOS Signature is incorrect.");
        }

        // ...

    }
    return null;
}
```

I expected to be able to simple use `stub->member` or `stub.member` however, stub appears to have no members.

Comment: Your struct members are private by default, that's why it appears to have no members. Adding "public" before every member declaration will make them visible: public UInt16 e_magic; etc

Comment: You might also want to look at making them into [Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties) instead of just public members

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing is that when you declare your struct like you do, all the members of your structure become private. That is why from outside it appears as having no members. This is pretty easy to solve, just add `public` before every member declaration:

```
struct MS_DOS_Stub
{
    public UInt16 e_magic;                     // Magic number
    // and so on and so forth
```

Re-interpreting your byte array as a struct is another thing. As far as I understand, you read your data from a file as a byte array and then you want to convert it into a struct. Your code, especially this part

```
fixed (byte* pBin = bin)
{
    MS_DOS_Stub* stub = (MS_DOS_Stub*)(pBin);
```

does not look good for me. Not only because it uses pointers, which is not the best thing one can do in C#. If you think about this, this approach (regardless if implemented in C# or C++) relies on the struct layout in memory, little endian/big endian architecture. Generally, you can not dump a section of memory into a file then read it back (probably on another computer!) and expect it to be a proper representation of a struct.

I don't know any solution to this which is both simple and robust. In your case, I would just use BitConverter to extract the parts of the structure I'm insterested in one by one. Like

```
stub.magic = BitConverter.ToInt16(bin, 0);
stub.e_cblp = BitConverter.ToInt16(bin, 2);
.....
stub.e_lfanew = BitConverter.ToInt32(bin, 60);
```

This code might be pretty long and verbose for a simple task, but it is guaranteed to work regardless of your environment. And also this way you don't have any `unsafe` code of pointer trickery, which is a good thing if you're programming in .Net.

Comment: Yes on making members public. But I think using BitConverter would miss the point a little.